# How to categorize New Relic transactions as web?

Tags: java, newrelic

When calling [`NewRelic.setTransactionName`](http://newrelic.github.io/java-agent-api/javadoc/com/newrelic/api/agent/NewRelic.html#setTransactionName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), how do you categorize a transaction as being web?

I tried passing "Web" and null and that resulted in categories named Web and Custom in the Non-Web section:

[image]

I also tried WebTransaction, uri and :uri, with the same outcome.

The reason is that I'm not using the usual New Relic integrations, so I have to do a bit more manual work to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `NewRelic.setRequestAndResponse()` method in the [transaction API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/api-guides/guide-using-java-agent-api#transactions).